# Existence of local isometric embedding of smooth $(M^{d-2},g)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm posting this question in hopes that someone more familiar with the literature will be able to point me in the right direction (or give an obvious answer).

Let $M^{d-2} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a smooth embedding and let $g$ be the metric induced on $M$ from the flat metric on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Under what conditions can $M$ be viewed (locally) as an isometrically-embedded hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$?

In the case where $d=3$, it is fairly clear: for a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$, if the torsion of the spacecurve vanishes, then the spacecurve is a planecurve. What is not clear to me is how this notion generalizes to higher dimensions.

I have considered two directions. My first guess is that there must exist a covariantly constant normal vector field in the normal bundle of $M$. This generalizes the notion that the direction of the binormal of a spacecurve is fixed when the spacecurve is actually a planecurve.

My second instinct is that there must exist a tensor $II \in \Gamma(\odot^2 T^* M)$ such that
$$R_{abcd} = II_{ac} II_{bd} - II_{ad} II_{bc}\,,$$
in line with the Gauss equation. Clearly, this condition is necessary but it is not obvious if it sufficient.

If anyone knows of literature on this subject, I'd love to be pointed in that direction. This seems like a rudimentary-enough question that it must have been studied. The literature I have found discusses the embeddability of surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ - this is always possible by the Burstin-Cartan-Janet Theorem, but it's a special case because $3$ is the Janet dimension for surfaces, and this coincidence does not hold for $d \geq 5$. The Nash embedding theorem seems to give upper bounds, but that's not exactly the kind of result I'm looking for.

Comment: The condition on the second fundamental form is not sufficient. I don't have an explicit example offhand, but for example it is possible to have a flat submanifold $M^{d-2} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ that does not lie in any hyperplane. The tensor $II$ has to be consistent with the second fundamental form of the $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Comment: Is this true locally or globally? Because I'm just looking for a local characterization.

Comment: The simplest one is that there exists a vector that is everywhere normal to the tangent space. In terms of the second fundamental form, note first that it is a vector-valued bilinear tensor. Then the condition is that there exits a constant normal vector such that the dot product of the vector with the second fundamental form is identically the zero symmetric 2-tensor.

Comment: @DeaneYang This is what I was thinking of with the phrase "there must exist a covariantly constant normal vector field." Are you suggesting that that is sufficient?

Comment: Do you want to know if $M^{d-2}$ sits inside a hyperplane in its given embedding in $\mathbb{R}^d$, or do you want to know if $M^{d-2}$ is locally isometric to a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$? Your question is asking for the second of these problems, but your example of the curve refers to the first of these problems.

Comment: @BenMcKay The former, at least locally. I could be wrong, but I was under the impression that if $M^{d-2}$ is embedded in in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and is locally isometric to a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$, then (at least locally) it would lie inside a hyperplane in its given embedding in $\mathbb{R}^d$. But if this is mistaken, please let me know.

Comment: @SamBlitz: Your example of a space curve in 3-space: all curves are locally isometric to the real number line. no need to consider torsion, to see that they are isometric to plane curves. You want to look at torsion to see if they are already in a plane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to answer the OP's question satisfactorily without considering what would actually constitute an answer.  The most obvious answer is tautological:  $M^{d-2}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ lies in a hyperplane if and only if there is a nonzero affine function $\ell:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\ell(M^{d-2}) = \{0\}$.  It seems clear that the OP wouldn't consider that criterion an answer though, because it requires one to test for the existence of something for which it may not be clear how to test.  Instead, it seems that the OP wants an answer of the form "If certain differential-geometric invariant quantities defined on $M^{d-2}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ vanish, then $M^{d-2}$ lies in a hyperplane.  One might also hope for a 'converse' that said that if $M^{d-2}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ lies in a hyperplane, then those quantities do vanish.

Here is a cautionary example worth considering:  Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $f(t) = 0$ for $t\le0$ and $f(t) = e^{-1/t}$ for $t>0$.  Now consider the smooth space curves $\alpha,\beta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$
\alpha(t) = \bigl(t,f(t),f(-t)\bigr)\quad\text{and}\quad
\beta(t) = \bigl(t,f(t)+f(-t),0\bigr)
$$
All of the differential invariants of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal (in particular, they both have vanishing torsion), but $\alpha(\mathbb{R})$ does not lie in a plane while $\beta(\mathbb{R})$ clearly does.

The issue is that if an immersed space curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ lies in a plane, then, $\gamma',\gamma'',\gamma'''$ must be linearly dependent, so in particular, the third order polynomial differential invariant $I_3 = (\gamma'\times\gamma'')\cdot\gamma'''\,(\mathrm{d}t)^6$ must vanish identically. However the vanishing of $I_3$, by itself, is not enough to guarantee that $\gamma'''$ is a linear combination of $\gamma'$ and $\gamma''$ with smooth coefficients (which would indeed imply that $\gamma(\mathbb{R})$ lay in a plane).  To get this, one needs an additional nondegeneracy condition, usually taken to be the condition that $\gamma'$ and $\gamma''$ be linearly independent.  (It turns out, though, that it suffices to impose the weaker nondegeneracy condition that the second order polynomial differential invariant $I_2 = (\gamma'\times \gamma'')\cdot(\gamma'\times \gamma'')\,(\mathrm{d}t)^6$ only vanish to finite order at any point of $\mathbb{R}$.)  [Note that, with regard to an element of arc-length $\mathrm{d}s$, defined up to a sign by $I_1 = (\gamma'\cdot\gamma')\,(\mathrm{d}t)^2 = (\mathrm{d}s)^2$, one has $I_2 = \kappa^2\,(\mathrm{d}s)^6$ and $I_3 = \tau\kappa^2(\mathrm{d}s)^6$, where $\kappa$ and $\tau$ have their usual meanings.]  In the above pair of examples, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same invariants $I_k$ for $k=1,2,3$, but $I_2$ vanishes to infinite order at $t=0$.

In higher dimensions, something similar has to be done, i.e., one has to identify conditions on the polynomial differential invariants of $M^{d-2}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ that hold when $M^{d-2}$ lies in a hyperplane and then impose nondegeneracy conditions before the vanishing of these invariants suffices to imply that $M^{d-2}$ does, in fact, lie in a hyperplane.

The most obvious condition (as mentioned by Yang and Petrunin) is that the rank $r$ of the second fundamental form $I\!I$ of $M$ should be at most $1$ at every point.  This is equivalent to the vanishing of a second order polynomial differential invariant that is asection of $\Lambda^2(S^2(T^*M))$ that we can write informally as $I_2 = {I\!I}\wedge{I\!I}$.  It's easy to see that the variety of second fundamental forms $I\!I$ at a point that satisfy this condition has codimension $\tfrac12 d(d{-}3)$, so this is already a fairly stringent condition as soon as $d>3$.

Another important invariant is what some authors call the *nullity* $\nu(p)$ of $I\!I$ at $p\in M$, i.e., the dimension of the subspace $N_p\subset T_pM$ consisting of the vectors $v\in T_pM$ such that ${I\!I}_p(v,u)=0$ for all $u\in T_pM$.  Note that bounding the nullity from above is an *open* condition on $I\!I$, so one can regard it as a nondegeneracy condition.

Using these terms, one has the following special case of a classic consequence of the structure equations:

**Theorem:** If $M^{d-2}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ has its second fundamental form of rank $r\le 1$ at every point and nullity at most $d{-}4$ at every point, then $M^{d-2}$ lies in a hyperplane.

Note that the above theorem is vacuous for $d=3$, but, for $d\ge 4$, it gives a sufficient criterion for $M$ to lie in a hyperplane that depends only on *second-order* information.  As we have seen, though, when the nullity is allowed to be as large as $d{-}3$, one has to go to third order information and, even then, put some condition on the locus where the nullity is as large as $d{-}2$ (i.e., where the second fundamental form vanishes) in order to conclude that $M$ lies in a hyperplane.

Comment: I appreciate this answer! Would you be able to point me toward some literature (or textbooks!) that contain this so I can read about it more? I haven't heard of the nullity in particular, so any recommendations you can make would be excellent.

Comment: Another thought I had initially is that if $M$ lies in a hyperplane, then a "normal fundamental form" (the language used by Spivak) should vanish for at least one choice of orthonormal frame of the normal bundle. Was I mistaken?

Comment: Have a look at the following paper and its references: R. B. Gardner,  *New viewpoints in the geometry of submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$*,  Bulletin of the AMS **83** (1977), 1–35.  I think you'll find it helpful.  (R. B. Gardner was my thesis advisor.). Certainly, if $M^{d-2}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ lies in a hyperplane, the rank of the second fundamental form is at most one, and, if it is $1$ everywhere, then there will be a normal vector field $n$ such that $n\cdot{I\!I}=0$, but that's not sufficient if the nullity of ${I\!I}$ is $d{-}3$, as the case $d=3$ shows.

Comment: Excellent, I'll take a look. Much appreciated.

Comment: So I've taken a look at the paper, and it look likes Proposition 2.1 is exactly what I am looking for. However, this looks like it doesn't have a nondegeneracy condition. Is the nondegeneracy implicit in Gardner's result that I am just not noticing?

Comment: @SamBlitz:  No, there's no nondegeneracy condition in his Prop 2.1, but his assumption is that you have found a normal vector $A$ satisfying $A\cdot I\!I = 0$. This is not a condition purely on the differential invariants of the submanifold.  For example, for curves (i.e., $d=3$ in your convention), this is not the condition that the torsion $\tau$ vanish, it's the condition that there exists a normal vector to the curve that is perpendicular to all of the principal normals of the curve.  This implies $\tau=0$, of course, but it's not equivalent to it, as the example I gave shows.

Comment: Ah, of course. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The case $d=4$ is an open problem.
It is easy to find a local embedding of any surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and
it is unknown if any surface is locally isometric to a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Now suppose $d\geqslant5$.
As you stated, the equation on the second fundamental form must have a solution.
Note that this solution is unique most of the time (see below); it may have different solutions only if the curvature vanish at the given point.

Let us assume that the curvature tensor is not zero at any point.
In this case we get first and second fundamental form on $M$ and it remains to answer if they correspond to a local embedding.
I am sure that there is an appropriate generalization of Peterson--Codazzi formulas that cover this case.

**Why the solution is almost unique.**
If solution exists, then the curvature tensor splits; that is, there is a orthonormal frame $e_1,\dots,e_{d-2}$ in the tangent space of $M$ at any point such that the $e_i\wedge e_j$ are eigenvectors of the curvature operator.
Morevoer, the $e_1,\dots,e_{d-2}$ are principal directions of the second fundamental form.
Denote by $K_{ij}$ the sectional curvature in the direction $e_i\wedge e_j$. Furhter, denote by $\kappa_i$ the principal curvature in the direction $e_i$. Then we have equations
$$\kappa_i\cdot\kappa_j=K_{ij}$$
for $i\ne j$.
If $K_{ij}=0$ for all $i$ and $j$, then we have many solution.
But if say $K_{ij}\ne0$ for some $i\ne j$, then
$$\kappa_m=\pm\sqrt{\frac{K_{im}\cdot K_{jm}}{K_{ij}}}$$
for any $m$ distinct from $i$ and $j$. (Here we need that $d\geqslant 5$.)
And now it is easy to get a unique solution up to sign.

Comment: Postscript. Your lines about case $d=3$ suggest that you have something else in mind, but I cannot guess what it was.

Comment: I think the OP is assuming an isometric embedding and wants a necessary and sufficient condition that the isometric embedding lies in a hyperplane.

Comment: On further thought, the question appears to be about finding a higher dimension analogue of the torsion of a curve in 3-space.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin That's quite surprising that the condition on the second fundamental form is (mostly) unique in $d \geq 5$ but not when $d = 4$. Can you explain why the natural generalization breaks down? About the $d=3$ case, it seems fairly clear to me that the condition for a spacecurve to live in a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is that its torsion vanishes. In that case, the torsion corresponds to the normal fundamental form, and I was hoping a generalization of that notion might be helpful.

Comment: @DeaneYang Sort of. Given $M^{d-2}$ a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^d$, I'm looking for conditions for which $M$ can be viewed as living in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @SamBlitz I added something to the answer.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I still don't think I follow. Using $d=5$ as an example, this seems like it implies a solution to the second fundamental form equation for embedding where $M \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$. But I'm interested in the case where, if we know that $M \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$, then when can we say that $M \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4 \subset \mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: @SamBlitz curvature operator of any hypersurface splits.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$The simplest condition is simply that there exists a nonzero vector $n \in \R^d$ such that for any $v \in T_pM$, $$ n\cdot v = 0. $$

If you write the embedding as a map $u: M \rightarrow \R^d$, where, with respect to local coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^{d-2})$ on $M$,
$$ \partial_iu\cdot \partial_ju = g_{ij},
$$
where $g = g_{ij}\,dx^i\,dx^j$ is the metric tensor on $M$. You can check that
$$
\partial^2_{ij}u = \Gamma^k_{ij}\partial_k + II_{ij},
$$
where $II$ is the second fundamental form. Since $M$ has codimension grater than $1$, each component of the second fundamental form is a vector $II_{ij} \in \R^d$ that is normal to $T_pM$.

Then, setting $v = \partial_i u$ and differentiating the equation
$$
n\cdot\partial_iu = 0,
$$
we get
\begin{align*}
0 &= \partial_j(n\cdot \partial_iu)\\
&= n\cdot \partial^2_{ij}u\\
&= n\cdot (\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_ku + II_{ij})\\
&= n\cdot II_{ij}.
\end{align*}
Now observe that the second fundamental form defines at each point $p \in M$ a linear map
\begin{align*}
II_p: T^\perp_pM &\rightarrow S^2T_pM\\
\nu &\mapsto \nu\cdot II_{ij}\partial_iu\otimes\partial_ju.
\end{align*}
The equation above implies that this map has rank at most $1$.

If you assume that $II$ always has rank equal to $1$, then there is a unique unit normal vector field $\nu$ such that
$$
\nu\cdot II_{ij} = 0.
$$
Differentiating this, we get (I think)
$$
0 = \partial_\nu\cdot II_{ij} + \nu\cdot \nabla_kII_{ij},
$$
where you have to define the connection appropriately (since $II_{ij}$ is not a tangent vector, this is not the Levi-Civita connection per se).

This finally leads to a **possible** answer that is analogous to the zero torsion condition for a space curve. A codimension 2 submanifold of $\R^d$ lies in a hyperplane if the following holds: The second fundamental form has rank 1, and if $n$ is a unit vector in the kernel, then
\begin{align*}
n\cdot \nabla II &= 0.
\end{align*}